# how do you insert multiple rows in a loop using doctrine 2

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

i want to insert multiple rows in a loop using doctrine 2..

i usually insert 1 record using this:

$Entity->setData($posted);
        $this->_doctrine->persist($Entity);
        $this->_doctrine->flush();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply persist all your objects and then call flush() after the loop.

```
    $entityDataArray = array();  // let's assume this is an array containing data for each entity
    foreach ($entityDataArray AS $entityData) {
        $entity = new \Entity();
        $entity->setData($entityData);
        $this->_doctrine->persist($entity);
    }
    $this->_doctrine->flush();
```

If you're inserting a large number of objects you will want to batch insert (see http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/batch-processing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop, you should be able to simply:

```
$entity1->setData($data1);
$this->_doctrine->persist($entity1);

$entity2->setData($data2);
$this->_doctrine->persist($entity2);

$this->_doctrine->flush();
```